# how to put a space after decimal value in csv using fputcsv?

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

[image]

This is the code i have used to write data into csv file.
Everything is working fine except decimal values!

```
$row[] = '14.31 ';
fputcsv($fp, $row, ',', '"');
```

i have a space after .31 `"14.31 "` so length should be `"6"` and now i am getting `"5"`.

how to include this space in the cell?

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine

Comment: Are you sure that the spreadsheet file you're using to view this csv isn't formatting the content? Look at the file in a text editor, not in MS Excel

Comment: P.S. You're not using `PHPExcel`, and a csv file isn't an xls file, so why the tags?

Comment: it is formatting the space! but i want the space! @Mark Baker

Comment: tag is removed @Mark

Comment: MS Excel will always do some formatting of data from a csv file.... there are a few ways you can try to avoid it, that may or may not work for you... option #1, prefix the value with a single quote before writing to csv (e.g. `'14.31 `), option #2, treat it as a string formula (e.g. `="14.31 "`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value to a variable and convert to string
Eg : $test ='14. 31 '; 
$row[] =(string) $test;

Or use double quotes 
 Eg: $test = "14.31" ;

Answer (score 0):

Intrigued by the question, ran 4 cases to see which delivers the desired result, CASE 4 should do the trick:

```
<?php
$fields[] = "case 1 - chr(32)";
$fields[] = "14.31 " . chr(32); // NO trailing space in .csv

$fields[] = "case 2 - chr(160)";
$fields[] = "14.31 " . chr(160); // 2 trailing spaces in .csv

$fields[] = "case 3 - rtrim + chr(32)";
$fields[] = rtrim("14.31 ", " ") . chr(32); // NO trailing space in .csv

$fields[] = "case 4 - rtrim + chr(160)";
$fields[] = rtrim("14.31 ", " ") . chr(160); // 1 trailing space in .csv

$fp = fopen('myfile.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, $fields);

fclose($fp);
?>
```